# Select Product Id's is Not Posting from product Grid on form submit in magento 2

Tags: magento2, product-grid

I am trying to add a product Grid in My Magento 2 admin form.

I followed [This](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/152092/77582) Tutorial and getting Grid on My frontend But On submit I am getting only `{}` in my save controller

The Problem Seems Like [This](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/210405/77582) But I have tried this one and Not getting success

Here is My `.phtml` file

```
<?php
$blockGrid = $block->getBlockGrid();
$gridJsObjectName = $blockGrid->getJsObjectName();
?>
<?php  echo $block->getGridHtml(); ?>
<input type="hidden" name="category_products" id="in_category_products" data-form-part="frontname_modulename_form" value="" />
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "*": {
            "Vendor_Module/products/assign-products": {
                "selectedProducts": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getProductsJson(); ?>,
                "gridJsObjectName": <?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo '"' . $gridJsObjectName . '"' ?: '{}'; ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
<!-- @todo remove when "UI components" will support such initialization -->
<script>
    require('mage/apply/main').apply();
</script>
```

here `frontname_modulename_form` is the namespace of my admin form

Here is my `assign-products.js` file

```
define([
    'mage/adminhtml/grid'
], function () {
    'use strict';

    return function (config) {
        var selectedProducts = config.selectedProducts,
            categoryProducts = $H(selectedProducts),
            gridJsObject = window[config.gridJsObjectName],
            tabIndex = 1000;

        $('in_category_products').value = Object.toJSON(categoryProducts);

        /**
         * Register Category Product
         *
         * @param {Object} grid
         * @param {Object} element
         * @param {Boolean} checked
         */
        function registerCategoryProduct(grid, element, checked) {
            if (checked) {
                if (element.positionElement) {
                    element.positionElement.disabled = false;
                    categoryProducts.set(element.value, element.positionElement.value);
                }
            } else {
                if (element.positionElement) {
                    element.positionElement.disabled = true;
                }
                categoryProducts.unset(element.value);
            }
            $('in_category_products').value = Object.toJSON(categoryProducts);
            grid.reloadParams = {
                'selected_products[]': categoryProducts.keys()
            };
        }

        /**
         * Click on product row
         *
         * @param {Object} grid
         * @param {String} event
         */
        function categoryProductRowClick(grid, event) {
            var trElement = Event.findElement(event, 'tr'),
                isInput = Event.element(event).tagName === 'INPUT',
                checked = false,
                checkbox = null;
            if (trElement) {
                checkbox = Element.getElementsBySelector(trElement, 'input');

                if (checkbox[0]) {
                    checked = isInput ? checkbox[0].checked : !checkbox[0].checked;
                    gridJsObject.setCheckboxChecked(checkbox[0], checked);
                }
            }
        }

        /**
         * Change product position
         *
         * @param {String} event
         */
        function positionChange(event) {
            var element = Event.element(event);

            if (element && element.checkboxElement && element.checkboxElement.checked) {
                categoryProducts.set(element.checkboxElement.value, element.value);
                $('in_category_products').value = Object.toJSON(categoryProducts);
            }
        }

        /**
         * Initialize category product row
         *
         * @param {Object} grid
         * @param {String} row
         */
        function categoryProductRowInit(grid, row) {
            var checkbox = $(row).getElementsByClassName('checkbox')[0],
                position = $(row).getElementsByClassName('input-text')[0];

            if (checkbox && position) {
                checkbox.positionElement = position;
                position.checkboxElement = checkbox;
                position.disabled = !checkbox.checked;
                position.tabIndex = tabIndex++;
                Event.observe(position, 'keyup', positionChange);
            }
        }

        gridJsObject.rowClickCallback = categoryProductRowClick;
        gridJsObject.initRowCallback = categoryProductRowInit;
        gridJsObject.checkboxCheckCallback = registerCategoryProduct;

        if (gridJsObject.rows) {
            gridJsObject.rows.each(function (row) {
                categoryProductRowInit(gridJsObject, row);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Please add your Vendor_Module/products/assign-products.js file code.

Comment: yes i have added this code l.. see my updated question

Answer (score 0):

You need to add namespace of form in your ui form xml file :

```
<item name="config" xsi:type="array">
      <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
      <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">example_form</item>
</item>
```

Replace your form name in **namespace** argument.

Clean cache and check it.

Comment: already tried this

Comment: Please upload your dataprovider file.

Comment: You need to set array of product id in field of array. You can set logic code in getData() function of dataprovider file.

Comment: can you please show me an example. I don't have an idea of how to do this

Comment: Like this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/153249/

Comment: okay i understand your point but I am unable to save on first submit..